# Is it possible to link a google analytics 4 property with two or more Bigquery project at same time?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

what the title says

I would like to know if it is possible to make two links with different BigQuery projects from the same ga4 property

1 GA4 property
2 BigQuery links with different project ids active at the same time.

thanks

```
I haven't found the answer anywhere
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. Once a BigQuery link has been established for a GA4 property, the Link button becomes disabled. You can, however, link multiple GA4 properties to a single BigQuery project. It will create a separate data set with the format `analytics_<property ID>` for each property.